# jQlite .find() traversing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I'm using an angular directive and I am not having any luck with the jQlite .find() method:

**DIRECTIVE**

```
function cardsList () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'CardsController',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/cards-list/cards-list.html',
        link: function ($scope, $element, attr, CardsController) {
                var cardLink = $element.find('a');

                console.log(cardLink);
            });

        }
    }
}

contextCards.directive('cardsList', cardsList);
```

An empty `[]` gets logged on the console.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="card in cards" class="cards--item">
    <a class="cards--link" data-ng-href="#/{{ card.slug }}">{{ card.title }}</a>
</li>
```

**VIEW**

```
<ul class="col-xs-12 cards--list" cards-list></ul>
```

All I want to do is traverse to the `<a>` elements. According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), `.find()` only works on tag names which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

EDIT: I want to add a class to the `<a></a>` if the card the link represents is selected (like `.current-card`)

Comment: The problem is most probably with the `ng-repeat` - try removing it to see that you *will* find the `<a>`. Why do you want to do DOM traversal? There may be other ways.

Comment: Exactly... `ng-repeat` takes its template (the `<li><a></a></li>`) out of DOM (transcluding it), and puts it there only after the link phase when its `$watchCollection` of the `cards` array is fired, which is why you're not seeing it. (Very well-formed question, btw,  +1)

Comment: You're both right `ng-repeat` is the problem. I want to add a class to the `<a></a>` if the card the link represents is selected (like `.current-card`). So I put the `<li>` in the view and just have `<a>` in the template. Is it good practice to `ng-repeat` a directive?

Comment: @DiegoHernandez, you should edit the question to add your ultimate goal. The solution could be simple with `ng-class` directive. Yes, it *is* a good practice the `ng-repeat` - that's what it is there for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answer it's not clear *how* the selected card is specified in the model, so I am assuming that the `card` object (the object of each iteration of `ng-repeat`) holds this flag, for example: `card.isSelected`.

Then, you could use `ng-class` to specify which CSS class to add based on this value:

```
<li ng-repeat="card in cards" class="cards--item">
    <a class="cards--link" 
       ng-class="{'current-card': card.isSelected}"
       ng-href="#/{{ card.slug }}">{{ card.title }}</a>
</li>
```

**Addendum:**

The answer to your original question about why `.find("a")` returns empty, it is because `ngRepeat` directive transcludes its content (which means that Angular takes the elements out of DOM during compilation), and places it at a later stage than your `link` function.